# Command Won't Ouput in Colour when Called from bashrc

Tags: bash, colors

I have the following in my `.bashrc`:

```
color_prompt=yes
force_color_prompt=yes
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='$(some_command)\$ '
else
    PS1='\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Where `some_command` is an executable that outputs a string with colours set. However when I use this for my prompt the colours are not there. If I execute the `some_command` manually the output has colour so I'm not sure why it doesn't when I add it to `.bashrc`.

Can anyone help? I'm a at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: @markp-fuso so this didn't work unfortunately. It again output but was not in colour.

Comment: @rowboat but this is a terminal prompt, wouldn't that be connected to a terminal? How would I go about testing/confirming this?

Comment: If it has a manual page, read that for a start. We can't really help when we don't know which command you are asking about.

Comment: I get no color if I put `PS1='$(grep --color=auto . /etc/timezone)\$ '` and if I switch to `--color=yes` I do.

Comment: @markp-fuso You usually _want_ your prompt command to be in single quotes, to have it re-execute every time the prompt is displayed, rather than hard-code the output from when you defined your prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so `some_command` above was using the [colored](https://crates.io/crates/colored) crate to set the colour of the text. This requires `CLICOLOR_FORCE` environment variable to be set. Once set everything works as expected.

Thank you @tripleee, @markp-fuso, and @rowboat for your help!